# Need to return existing data structure with update objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I wanted to update the object when it pass the check but getting different result then expected.
What is preferred way to get the expected?

This the sample data:

```
    var abc = [
            {
            type: "manager",
            members: [{name: 'bob'}, {name: 'rob'}]
            },
            {
            type: "clerk",
            members: [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}]
            }
            ];
```

Using this function :

```
    function funn() {
      return abc.map((cate) => {
        return cate.members.map((mem) => {
          if (mem.name === 'bob') {
            mem['isBob'] = true;
          }
          return mem;
        });
      });
    }
```

I wanted in this format (expected):

```
[
  {
    type: 'manager',
    members: [{ name: 'bob', isBob: true }, { name: 'rob' }],
  },
  {
    type: 'clerk',
    members: [{ name: 'foo' }, { name: 'bar' }],
  },
];
```

The actual is like this:

```
[
  {
    members: [{ name: 'bob' }, { name: 'rob' }],
  },
  {
    members: [{ name: 'foo' }, { name: 'bar' }],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find the element in the `members` array and if it is present then add the `isBob` property.

```js
var abc = [{
    type: "manager",
    members: [{
      name: "bob"
    }, {
      name: "rob"
    }],
  },
  {
    type: "clerk",
    members: [{
      name: "foo"
    }, {
      name: "bar"
    }],
  },
];

const result = abc.map((obj) => {
  const isExist = obj.members.find((o) => o.name === "bob");
  if (isExist) isExist.isBob = true;

  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you showed for your code is not matching when i run it.
Here I have modified your code a bit:

Instead of returning an array from the outer .map(), I am returning an object which has a type and members category.

```
function funn() {
      return abc.map((cate) => {
        let cateMembers = cate.members.map((mem) => {
          if (mem.name === 'bob') {
            mem['isBob'] = true;
          }
          return mem;
        });
        return { type : cate.type , members : cateMembers};
      });
    }
```

Remember to check like this : `console.log(funn())`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
 var abc = [
            {
            type: "manager",
            members: [{name: 'bob'}, {name: 'rob'}]
            },
            {
            type: "clerk",
            members: [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}]
            }
            ];

             function funn() {
            abc.forEach(el => {
                el.members.forEach(el2 => {
                    if(el2.name === 'bob') el2.isBob = true
                })
            })
            return abc
    }

    console.log(funn())
```